# remove follow this site from sharing email

Tags: 2013, email-templates

In SharePoint 2013 sharing content or a site generates an email to the user which contains a link to the content and information. It also contains an option to follow the content or site...is there a way to remove this from those emails?

Answer (score 1):

This technically is possible, however you would be editing the resource files installed by SharePoint. **Doing this is NOT supported by Microsoft**, could break things, and could get overwritten during future updates.

If you are feeling adventurous in a test environment, however, the location of the resource files is here: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources`.

- [Customise the email sent via the "Share" feature in Sharepoint 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/164b28b3-573b-4b03-bf26-d91a355e0698/customise-the-email-sent-via-the-share-feature-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin)